# Mixing Pure React Components with Om Next

Tags: clojure, reactjs, clojurescript, om

Suppose I have access to a pure react.js component via some library:

```
var MyPureJavaScriptComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    //...
  }
});
```

But I wish to use om.next, where React components are constructed via the `defui` macro:

```
(defui MyComponent
  Object
  (render [this]
          (div nil "Hello, world!")))
```

**Question:** What is the best way to get `MyPureJavaScriptComponent` into `om.next`? It would be really nice (aesthetically, at least) if it could be wrapped inside its own call to `defui` so that `MyPureJavaScriptComponent` was on the same footing as every other om.next component. Is this possible (and would it be the best way to go about it)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can return any React component to render into your Om.next tree, here is one example:

```
(defui MyComponent
  Object
  (render [this]
    (dom/div nil
      (dom/h1 nil "Hello")
      (js/React.createElement js/MyPureJavaScriptComponent #js {:prop "value"}))))
```

Comment: Isn't there a better place to create it than in the render function, for instance when it is mounted? But this way is simple and is helped by the fact that React doesn't do any unnecessary real rendering.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy this is the recommended way, the normal React JSX syntax just abstracts this away, but check the sources and you will see `React.createElement` all over the place, check this example from React main page (check on the Compiled JS tab) https://www.dropbox.com/s/9asp89ebb201el8/Screenshot%202016-02-28%2020.47.07.png?dl=0